# onAppear not displaying Interface Elements

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I am having a weird issue where in my view stack, .onAppear is running my function to pull data from my server, but it fails to display card elements that I have created for the interface. What I am trying to achieve is when the user opens the app and it takes them to the dashboard it will show the various headlines of the platform. I am not getting any errors, as the JSON Object is being read correctly.

Some things that I have read is that the view may need to be updated after .onAppear is called, but the resources I have found don't really explain how to do so. The first bit of code is my JSON Object:

```
{"results" : [{"id":1,"title":"Meet ergoWare","header_image":"http://gba.ergoware.io/cache/content/topstory/ergo_news_01.svg","summary":"GBA's New Ergonomic Portal!"}]}
```

That is pulled in through this function

```
func loadHeadlines(CDNLink: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: CDNLink) else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            return
        } else {
            do {
                let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!)
                    print(decodedResponse)
                self.results = decodedResponse.results
                } catch let err {
                    print("Error parsing: \(err)")

                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Then tagging on .onAppear to my HStack, it preforms the function and runs my ForEach Statement like so

```
ScrollView(showsIndicators: false){
                Text("HEADLINES")
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(results) { result in
                            CardView(image: result.header_image, heading: result.title, summary: result.summary)
                        }
                    }.onAppear(perform:{self.loadHeadlines(CDNLink: "http://\(self.defaults.object(forKey: "domain") as! String)/cdn?funct=fetchNews")})
                }
```

So my question is, why is the CardView not showing when the scene loads? Using Simulator, if I build and test the app, then switch out of the app and back in, the cards start showing up. Thank you for any insight you can provide. Below I have some links to my full code.

[Dashboard View](https://pastebin.com/Tih6WXh9)
[CardView](https://pastebin.com/694usU9G)

Comment: try to call your network call in init() method of the struct or try on the first `VStack` of the body

Comment: @Mac3n that was a good suggestion, but that unfortunately did not solve the problem. In struct DashboardView: View, I added in ```init() { self.loadHeadlines(CDNLink: "http://\(self.defaults.object(forKey: "domain") as! String)/cdn?funct=fetchNews") }``` and it preformed the network call, it just did not cause the cards to show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify the difference between init and onAppear() (accoding to comments)

Let's imagine you have a TabView with 2 views. First view is the view you created and provided code for, the second view could be a profile view. onAppear() function will be called each time the user switch between these two TabViews while init() function will only run once in this particular use case.

Next, it is important to note that URLSession is running on background thread. You can only update the Views from the MainThread which means, you should encapsulate the result into:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.results = decodedResponse.results
}
```

**But the acutal answer to your Question**

I just faced the same issue few days ago. ScrollView has some bug/feature at this moment, which means, if you try to ScrollView + ForEach an empty array that is going to be updated later it will not show up. If you give a hardcoded Article as your first item, and update the rest later, it will work. Atleast for me worked under swift5 xcode 11.3.1 on iOS 13.3.1. However I use ObservableObject to handle datas in a class and ObservedObject to take advantage of @Published modifier. Like this

```
class Result : ObservableObject{
    @Published var results = [Article]()
}
```

And Write this to your swiftUI code:

```
@ObservedObject private var data = Result()
```

Your swiftui init function should contain an add function like so to bypass ScrollView bug/feature:

```
init() {
    self.data.results.append(....)
    self.callYourRestAPIHere(URL:"whateverhere", result: data)
}
```

Hope I did not miss anything, but I am ready to improve my Answer if I did.

Comment: I keep getting an error on Line 96: ```'Int' is not convertible to 'CGFloat?'```. Also shouldn't it be ```@Published var results = [Article]()```? I am trying to understand this, but I am admittedly lost.

Comment: Give me some places to chat with you so we can rapidly identify your issues and solve them, this modification should make your code work since it worked for me on the mentioned environment

Comment: We can email at tbelldesignco@gmail.com and I can host a zoom meeting and share out my screen.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should identify the data in the ForEach loop so SwiftUI can distinguish the different data items and can properly see if the content of the array have been changed. Like this:

```
ForEach(results, id: \.id) { result in
    CardView(image: result.header_image, heading: result.title, summary: result.summary)
}
```